# What is Solidity revert code "-32000" when interacting with contracts via Remix IDE?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I wonder if the error "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert", "code": -32000" thrown by the Remix IDE indicates the 0x32 Solidity panic exception happening when you access array out-of-bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error codes are documented at [EIP 1474 - Remote procedure call specification](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1474).

In this case

| Code | Message | Meaning | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -32000 | Invalid input | Missing or invalid parameters | non-standard |

It is a generic error code returned by RPC provider when the call has failed.